# CodeSmith Templates for Entity Framework Code First

Tags: entity-framework, templates, ef-code-first

Does anybody know if there have been any code-first templates created by the CodeSmith community?  I see in their next version they are planning support, but was curious if someone in the community is planning on creating one.  I have an older copy, so won't get new templates in their new version.

I didn't see any, hence the post if anyone has.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any publicly distributed set of templates for EF4 and CodeSmith Generator. The templates we are creating will work on CodeSmith Generator 5.x. If you check our [twitter](http://twitter.com/#!/codesmithtools) we have a special offer that could be used for a license or upgrade. By upgrading you will benefit from a lot of enhancements and features / bug fixes. Plus you will be getting access to managed and supported EF4 templates (which are free and open source).

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski